# Getting Error : [Err] 1615 - Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared with MySQL 5.6.30

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, view, dynamic-sql, prepared-statement

Problem/Issue : Getting Error :  `[Err] 1615 - Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared`

I have a Stored Procedure which contains a Prepared Statement and a view

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sampleProc`;

DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sampleProc`()
BEGIN

SET @select = "SELECT * FROM `viewSample` ";

  PREPARE stmt FROM @select ;
  EXECUTE stmt ;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt ;

END  ;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Following call sometimes gives error `CALL sampleProc();`

**Possible work around / solutions**

It appears that the best solution is to increase the value of table_definition_cache , but it seems that it is not working , as it had already been increased from 1400 (default) to 16384. table_open_cache is also been increased to 32162

```
Variable_name               Value
table_definition_cache      16384
table_open_cache            32162
table_open_cache_instances  4
```

Answer (score 7):

This seems to be an on-going issue

Views are messy to handle with Dynamic SQL

Earliest Bug was [Cannot create VIEWs in prepared statements from 11 years ago. There was a patch put in to address it](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=13095).

Another bug report, [Prepared-Statement fails when MySQL-Server under load](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=42041), states that error 1615 is not a bug when the underlying tables are busy. (Really ?)

While there is some merit to increasing the table cache size (See [MySql error when working with a mysql view](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/mysql-general-error-1615-prepared-statement-needs-to-be-re-prepared?page=1)), it does not always work (See [General error: 1615 Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared (selecting mysql view)](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/general-error-1615-prepared-statement-needs-to-be-re-prepared-selecting-mysql-view?page=1))

### ALTERNATIVES

Over a year ago, someone mentioned this in the [MySQL Forum (MySql “view”, “prepared statement” and “Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared”)](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?100,630131,630131).

Someone came up with [the simple idea of not using the view in the prepared statement but using the SQL of view in a subquery instead](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?100,630131,630158#msg-630158). Another idea would be to [create the SQL used by the view and execute it in your client code](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/general-error-1615-prepared-statement-needs-to-be-re-prepared-selecting-mysql-view/replies/87865).

These would seems to be better workarounds that just bumping up the table cache size.